# How do you use "Scroll To" to factor in the fixed nav heights at different media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my banner. This button, when clicked, I'd like it to scroll me to the div below the banner. This is the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

When I click on it it'll scroll me, but it'll scroll me past the `div`. What I believe I need to do is factor in the height of the fixed nav and possibly the `padding-top` of the div I'm scrolling to.

The next thing is, what if I'm in the mobile view now and the height of the nav changes? How do I factor that in?

I suck at Javascript so any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but you could use [this plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) instead of having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, so you can modify the scroll length

```
function scrollNav() {
      $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 160
        }, 400);
     return false;
  });
};
```